# When I move between the pages in the hybrid app, I can see the previous one for a seconds. And issue for changing CSS

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-activity, webview

I'm currently working on making hybrid-app.
(Using jquery mobile.)
I have some problems on rendering webview in the application.

1. There are lists and detail pages with html. when the transition happens, the screen displays white screen, a previous page for a seconds, white screen and then displays detail page. And it goes to the same when I click a back button.

is this a cache problem or hardware accelerate?

2. I separated css file from one whole one while the application was on service. And there was css rendering problem until i did "clear date" on mobile not "clear cache". CSS didn't seem like working at all on the page.

Is this a issue of jquery mobile? or is this also the cache problem? then why didn't it work when i did "clear cache" but "clear data"?
And what will happen if i put this?:

context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");

will all data saved be deleted? like, settings people using now?

Comment: are you using emulator?

Comment: before back-end development, I check it on with chrome developer tools. but after making it as an app (apk file), we try it with our devices.

Comment: i have the same problem using cordova ionicframework, but its only occur in emulator

Comment: no in real device? or have you tried the real one?

Comment: yes, i have tried it on real device and publish it, and still got no feedback about this problem. maybe its in your code. show some code related to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Two topics I noticed in the context of page transitions and jqm:

A) rendering of a page takes some time and have impact on the transition. If you generate/update your detailed page, wait until everything has finished before the page transition starts (can be achieved with setTimeout(...,  10)

B) unfortunately, all pages in jqm are scrolling together and are not independent from each other. I noticed that before a page transition starts,  the current page is scrolled to the top. Afterwards the new page appears. Looks ugly... Unfortunately several css settings must be modified to change this behaviour.

Hope this helps, 
Andreas